# PyCharm will not show my python interpreter even when I have PyCharm create a new enviroment

Tags: pycharm

I'm at a loss of what to do here. I have created a virtual environment for my current project, but PyCharm for some reason will not add my python interpreter.

```
File -> Settings -> Project -> Python Interpreter -> 
Add -> Existing environment -> ...\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

I hit ok, and when I go to select my new interpreter from the drop down, it's missing. I've even tried creating a new environment with PyCharm, but still nothing will show. I've restarted my computer. Made sure everything was closed. Restart PyCharm. But I cannot seem to add a new interpreter. Even when I have PyCharm create the environment!

Comment: For whatever reason, after deleting a few invalid interpreters, PyCharm will finally detect the one I just created and I can see it. So I guess the problem solved itself, but I don't know why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Reinstall PyCharm.  That will usually (if not always) fix any issue that might crop up.  You should be able to do this without loss of any project works etc.

Comment: This is not good advice and should be the last thing to do.

Comment: @bad_coder - given a few interpreters have mistakenly been deleted, and given the individual has attempted creating a new environment, restarted, and still cannot add an interpreter; and given it's been posted to StackOverflow - and still nothing....PTO

Comment: (continued)- it's seems like the quickest and cleanest thing to do that will cause the least stress and ensure everything is functioning in order as it should. I DISAGREE with you - I do this regularly when I run into a wedge... PTO...

Comment: (continued)...It's quick, easy, clean, and there's very little risk of going wrong - files should be in order; only thing will be that a few libraries will need to be reinstalled again. Take a chill pill - nothing wrong with my proposed. It may be the case that the interpreter issue is solved, but something else more serious is still foul/at play with an alterative approach.  I'd say just make a backup copy of your scripts and export preferences  in first instance

Comment: Thank you! I thought about reinstalling pycharm, but I thought to check to see if there was some weird setting that I might have check/unchecked to have caused the issue. And for me, reinstalling pycharm is not a huge hassle. So if this pops up again, I'll probably do that.

Comment: @TylerSingleton - best of luck, don't forget to vote ! :)